# Internet Accessible Private Cloud

Tags: linux, networking, virtual-machine, internet, relay

I am attempting to setup a private cloud server (using a Debian VM) that is accessible to myself and a few friends over the internet. I have a domain name, however I do not have a public IP or access to the router to create a DMZ or port forward.

I have thought of using something like Teamviewer, but only one person would be able to use it at a time and a GUI would be needed. What other methods can be used to allow us to gain access to the server? I would prefer a solution that doesn't involve using a relay server, or a free/inexpensive solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://serverfault.com/questions/785929/internet-accessible-private-cloud

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to create a VPN. And there are plenty of ways to do that. What I recommend, from the most simple to the most complicated:

1. Hamachi (limited to 8 user/network in free version)
2. PPTP (just `apt-get install pptpd` on the server and add the users) because it's built in Windows clients (I don't know for Linux)
3. OpenVPN, for which there are numerous tutorials on the Internet. Best solution security-wise, and cross-platform too (including smartphones)

**EDIT**: 4. You can create a hidden TOR service on the client, wich would be accessible as a website with `.tor` domain extension. This doesn't require access to the public IP provided by the server's ISP, be would need clients **and** server to be able to access TOR. And connection would be slow.

Comment: I too think a VPN is the best way. But the main issue is that there isn't a defined path to the server without the public IP or even access to the router. I've been looking at SoftEther as a possibility because they also offer a free relay service on vpnazure.net. Are there any other solutions out there that can create that link from internet to server with an arbitrary number of hops?

Comment: One thing I didn't think about: connect your server and clients to the TOR network, create a hidden TOR service on the server for your cloud and then use TOR name resoultion to access the server. There are two drawbacks, however. Your ISPs (for clients *and* server) would have to allow TOR traffic, and the connexion would be quite slow.